# React Hook "useQuery" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to retrieve my data only at submit event, when the user is inserting the query parameter.

It doesn't like this line of code  `if (first)  { const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(search_reviews, {variables: {my_query: query}}) }`
I checked other posts, but I am not able to see a tweak for what I need. Maybe I am tired, but I would appreciate your guidance and help!

Please find bellow my full code.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";


const search_reviews= gql`
 query SearchReviews ($my_query: String!) {
    reviews (filters: {or: [{body: {contains: $my_query} }, {title: {contains: $my_query}}]}) {
      data{
        id
        attributes{
          title
          rating
          body
          categories{
            data{
              id
              attributes
              {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  
 }
}

`


export default function Test() {
    const [ first, setFirst ] = useState(false)
    const [ query, setQuery] = useState("")



    if (first)  {
        const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(search_reviews, {variables: {my_query: query}})
    }


    if (loading) return <p>Loading data...</p>
    if (error) return <p>Error fetching data</p>
    console.log(data)


    return (
        <div>

            <div className="wrap">
                <div className="search">
                    <form onSubmit={e => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        console.log(e.target[0].value)

                        setQuery(e.target[0].value)
                        setFirst(true)


                    }}>
                        <input type="text"
                               placeholder="Search Malware"
                               className="searchTerm"
                               id="input_text"
                                />
                        <button type="submit" className="searchButton">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            {first && (
            <div className="dataResult">
                    {data.reviews.data.map(review => (
                        <div key={review.id} className="review-card">
                        <div className="rating">{review.attributes.rating}</div>
                        <h2>{review.attributes.title}</h2>

                        {review.attributes.categories.data.map(c => (
                            <small key={c.id}>{c.attributes.name}</small>
                            ))}

                            <p>{review.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}... </p>
                            <Link to={`/details/${review.id}`}>Read more</Link>
                            </div>
                            ))}

            </div>
                )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hello, you must **not** use hooks conditionnaly https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Thank you! I have read the docs, I know about this, but I don't know how can I tweak the code, in order to work. This hook is from graphql and i need to use it as per the docs above. But I need my data to fire only after I have that boolen first true.

Comment: maybe the `skip` option could make the trick?
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#skip

Comment: Thank you! where to put this skip? As per the docs, this skip is only used at filed level and not at query level. Could you please show me how can be added to my graphql query?

Comment: I think `useQuery(search_reviews, {skip: !first, variables:...})`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! @dbuchet U rock!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the final answer:

```
const SEARCH= gql
 query SearchReviews ($my_query: String!) {
    reviews (filters: 
        {or: [{body: {contains: $my_query} }, 
        {title: {contains: $my_query}}]},
    sort:"createdAt:desc",
    pagination: {start: 0, limit: 100}
    ) {
      data{
        id
        attributes{
          title
          rating
          body
          createdAt
          categories{
            data{
              id
              attributes
              {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  
 }
}
```